# Cómo generar una tabla con rowspan dinamicos.

Tags: php, array, html-tabla

Quiero generar una tabla con `rowspan` los cuales dependan del numero de 'departamentos repetidos', por el momento mi tabla se genera normal.

```html
<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Departamento</th><th>Empleado</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>RH</td><td>Jose H</td></tr><tr><td>RH</td><td>Ana M</td></tr><tr><td>RH</td><td>Carlos</td></tr><tr><td>Produccion</td><td>Hector</td></tr><tr><td>Produccion</td><td>Marco</td></tr><tr><td>lineas</td><td>Jesus</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

La idea es que si algun departamento esta repetido que solo aparesca una sola vez, como en el ejemplo.

```html
<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Departamento</th><th>Empleado</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td rowspan="3">RH</td><td>Jose H</td></tr><tr><td>Ana M</td></tr><tr><td>Carlos</td></tr><tr><td rowspan ="2">Produccion</td><td>Hector</td></tr><tr><td>Marco</td></tr><tr><td>lineas</td><td>Jesus</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

EL código que utilizo para generar la primera tabla es:

```
<?php
 // arreglo perteneciente al resultado de una consulta.
$datos = [
    ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Jose H'],
    ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Ana M'],
    ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Carlos'],
    ['departamento'=> 'Produccion', 'empleado'=> 'Hector'],
    ['departamento'=> 'Produccion', 'empleado'=> 'Marco'],
    ['departamento'=> 'lineas', 'empleado'=> 'Jesus']];


$tabla = '<table><thead><tr><th>Departamento</th><th>Empleado</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
for ($i=0; $i <count($datos) ; $i++) { 
    $tabla.='<tr><td>'.$datos[$i]['departamento'].'</td><td>'.$datos[$i]['empleado'].'</td></tr>';
}
$tabla .= '</tbody></table>';

echo $tabla;
```

Los datos del arreglo pertenecen al resultado de una consulta a una base de datos, lo cual podría variar el numero de resultados, los datos estar ordenados por departamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te tocaría hacer un recorrido por los datos, previo a mostrarlos en la tabla, de modo de averiguar cuántas filas se agrupan por Departamento:

```
    <?php
        // arreglo perteneciente al resultado de una consulta.
    $datos = [
        ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Jose H'],
        ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Ana M'],
        ['departamento'=> 'RH', 'empleado'=> 'Carlos'],
        ['departamento'=> 'Produccion', 'empleado'=> 'Hector'],
        ['departamento'=> 'Produccion', 'empleado'=> 'Marco'],
        ['departamento'=> 'lineas', 'empleado'=> 'Jesus']];

    /* Esto es para averiguar por cuántas filas hay que agrupar cada Depto: */
    $rowspan = array();
    foreach ($datos as $fila)
    {
        $rowspan[$fila["departamento"]]++;
    }

   /* Acá le di border=1 a la tabla sólo para que se noten las celdas generadas: */
    $tabla = "<table border='1'><thead><tr><th>Departamento</th><th>Empleado</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

    for ($i=0; $i < count($datos) ; $i++) 
    {
        $tabla .= "<tr>";
        if (isset($rowspan[$datos[$i]["departamento"]]))
        {
            $tabla .= '<td rowspan="'.$rowspan[$datos[$i]["departamento"]].'">'.$datos[$i]['departamento'].'</td>';
            unset($rowspan[$datos[$i]["departamento"]]);
        }
        $tabla .= "<td>".$datos[$i]['empleado']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $tabla .= "</tbody></table>";

    echo $tabla;
    ?>
```

Esto lo probé en [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).

Comment: me funciona perfecto gracias, lo que no se es por que me muestra el mensaje:
-> Undefined index: RH
-> Undefined index: Produccion
->Undefined index: lineas

dependiendo el numero de departamentos muestra un mensaje similar

Comment: Sí, a mí también me lo muestra, pero ten en cuenta 2 cosas: (1) los índices son los nombres de Depto que asigné dentro de `$rowspan`, los cuales luego llamamos al crear `$tabla`, sin haberlos previa y explícitamente declarado antes y (2) ese tipo de mensaje es un aviso de algo irregular en el código, pero que no genera error fatal, por lo que puede pasarse por alto si no tienes tiempo de corregirlo (lo cual, claro no debemos, jijiji).